# What does |= means in PHP?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

PHP. Can somebody explain me what

> |=

means in the following lines of code?

```
$mark = true;
$options = FT_UID;
if(!$mark) { 
  $options |= FT_PEEK;
}
```

I've read |  is a *bitwise operation* which operates on bits but I still don't get it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is read "OR equals."  So it ors the lvalue with the rvalue and assigns to the lvalue.

```
$a = 0;
..
$a |= $b
```

is the same as

```
$a = $a | $b
```